# Django KeyError: 'parent'

Tags: django

What i am trying to do is i try to check if the user has parent or not,then to authorize the serialization operation.But i get an error that says:

```
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/root/server/accounts/serializers.py", line 715, in validate
    if (attrs['parent'] == None) and (attrs['id'] == self.context['request'].user.pk):
KeyError: 'parent'
```

**Models.py**

```
class MyModel(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name =models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True,default='name')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields  = ('id','name','password','parent')


    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if (attrs['parent'] == None) and (attrs['id'] == self.context['request'].user.pk):
            return attrs
        elif (attrs['parent'].id != self.context['request'].user.pk) and (attrs['parent'] != None):
            raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
        return attrs
```

Does anybody know the issue of the problem?

Comment: Use `.get(key)` instead of `[key]` if you want `None` returned for non-existing keys instead of having a `KeyError` raised. See https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/#the-usual-solution-get

Comment: So, `attrs.get('parent')` .. Right?

Comment: Issue is solved.Thanks!